# JScrollPane component change

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

i have a JScrollPane.
But default it displays JTextArea.

```
JTextArea jTextArea = new JTextArea();
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(jTextArea);
```

so here everything is fine. But now i would like to change JScrollPane component by user action:

```
pane.remove(jTextArea);
pane.add(new JTable(data[][], columns[]));
pane.revalidate();
frame.repaint();
```

frame in my main Window. JScrollPane is added to main window with GridBagLayout.
But this doesn't work. After running action JScrollPane becomes grey.

Comment: Seems it is overdue you accepted an answer on this one!

Answer (score 4):

```
jScrollPane.getViewport().remove/add
```

Comment: @Ruslan works fine, something wrong with the code you are not showing, that is time for an sscce :-)

Comment: the `JScrollPane.setViewportView(...)` or `JViewport.setView(...)`  methods should be used instead of remove/add/revalidate/repaint.

Answer (score 3):

One alternative is to put a `JPanel` with a `CardLayout`<sup>1</sup> into the `JScrollPane`, add both the components to the panel, then simply flip between the text area and table as needed.

1. [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

---

Given the components might be of vastly different size, it might be better to do it this way:

`JPanel` with `CardLayout` contains *many* `JScrollPane` instances, each of which contains a single component.  That will also work inherently better for a `JTable`.

Answer (score 2):

Edited my answer after receiving one valuable suggestion by His Majesty @camickr, `setViewportView(componentObject);` is used to do such things.

A sample code to help your cause :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ScrollPaneExample extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel panel;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JTextArea tarea;
    private JTextPane tpane;
    private JButton button;
    private int count;

    public ScrollPaneExample()
    {
        count = 0;
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationByPlatform(true);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        tarea = new JTextArea();
        tarea.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        tarea.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        tarea.setText("TextArea is working");
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tarea);

        tpane = new JTextPane();
        tpane.setText("TextPane is working.");

        button = new JButton("Click me to CHANGE COMPONENTS");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    scrollPane.setViewportView(tpane);
                    count++;
                }
                else if (count == 1)
                {
                    scrollPane.setViewportView(tarea);
                    count--;
                }
            }
        });

        setContentPane(panel);
        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new ScrollPaneExample();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this might help you in some way.

Regards

Comment: the `JScrollPane.setViewportView(...)` or `JViewport.setView(...)`  methods should be used instead of remove/add/revalidate/repaint.

Comment: @camickr : Thankyou, for guiding me on this, I didn't knew about this. That's a wonderful suggestion, I edited my answer.  Regards